# git log A..B show shared commits

Tags: git

why `git logs tagA..tagB` shows shared commits?

Let's say I have `master` with `4`commits: `aa`, `bb`, `cc`, `dd`.

I'm tagging master twice (using `tag -a ${name of tag} -m "some msg"`).

tagA has two commits: `aa`, `bb`. tagB has all commits: `aa`, `bb`, `cc`, `dd`.

I'm using `git log tagA..tagB` and instead of getting commits `cc` and `dd`, I'm getting all commits. `git log` show shared commits as well.

How can I deal with it?
How can I show only additional commits from `tagB`?

Comment: It shouldn't. It should only show commits from `tagA` to `tagB` - Are you sure you tagged correctly? Can you share `gitk` screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you did not tagged your project correctly.

When executing `git log A...B` git simply find out what are the SHA-1 of A & B and show the diff between them

In your case when using tags git simply change the tag names with the given commit which the tag was attached to.

Use this to verify that your tags on attached to the right commits:

```
git log --oneline --decorate --graph
```

Now you should see the tgas next to the desired commit.
I assume you will find the tag to be pointing to the wrong commit.

Here you can see the tag in yellow and the commit which its pointing to.

[image]